# How can I get Laravel and ReactJS working? I have both ready, separetely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel-5, redux, laravel-blade

I want to make an application for which I use ReactJS for front-end and Laravel for the back-end. I have both ready, the Laravel part is done and so is the ReactJS.

I tried the most stupid thing a sane person would do, copy-paste ReactJS build folder to the Laravel's views folder and Laravel's assets folder. It does not seem to be working. It says missing references to all JavaScript and CSS files.

I changed index.html into index.blade.html.

And, I thought, perhaps, I linked to a wrong path for CSS and the JavaScript. I changed `/static/css/main.ac1cfcf0.css` to `main.ac1cfcf0.css` and `/static/js/main.551bf7d2.js` to `main.551bf7d2.js` in my index.blade.html but I still receive the same error.

What can I do to integrate the front-end and back-end into one project properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel Mix, you can easily create and transform your JS files to use ES6 and React: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#react

In your webpack.mix.js file, compile your assets like this:

`mix.react('resources/assets/js/react-app.jsx', 'public/js');`

Then, in your blade file, bring in your bundle like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/react-app.min.js') !!}"></script>`

Comment: Where should I put the webpack.mix.js? And, is the react-app.jsx a build codes or pre-build ReactJS codes?

Comment: react-app.jsx should be replaced with whatever your React entrypoint is. webpack.mix.js would go in your root folder. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix